Google Apps Script doGet() function not recognizing query string
I am communicating with google apps script with the following:
$.get(url, "name=alice&n=1&n=2", function(data) {
        ...

}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        ...
});

The outgoing request url is:
.../exec?name=alice&n=1&n=2

The problem I am encountering is that on the apps-script side, the doGet function doesn't seem to be recognizing the existence of the query string.  I have the following doGet function:
function doGet(e) {
  var groupNumber = e.queryString;
  if (groupNumber != null) {
      return A
  } else {
      return B
  }
}

The problem I am encountering is that the variable groupNumber is always getting set to null and thus the B is always getting returned, and not A.  I have saved and deployed the app script and am using the up-to-date url.

Maybe jquery is not sending it as query string?  Try logging e on the server side: console.log(JSON.stringify(e))

I've created an example in Google Apps Script, maybe this could help you find if something is missing.

If you want to use queryString it will return a string and you should split the string to extract the values.

If you use parameter you can destructure the key you pass through the url.


Code Example
function doGet(e) {
  const { name } = e.parameter; // < -- Extracting the key of the query parameter.

  const queryString = e.queryString; // < -- Reading the query as a String.

  const res = `queryString: ${queryString} <br> name: ${name}`;
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(res);
}

URL Example using queryString & parameter
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyeHSAQCAwhozU0hoLYf0e0jgXV7PsiCIfPzpm2Zh5Dm-a1tRR3t-J9sfLv6P1aYAo/exec?name=John
